# Using tar to copy files without parent directory

Tags: tar

I'm trying to use `tar` to copy `my_folder` from a directory to another one. I would like to adapt this code but I can't figure out how to remove parent directories when the folder the folder is extracted.

```
tar cf - /f1/f2/my_folder | tar -C /f1/f3/f4/ -xf -
```

Would anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Fastest copying (typically at least 10% faster than any other copy method) is done with `star`, e.g. with `star -copy -C fromdir . todir` and without the parent directories. Note that you should add the option `-no-fsync` in case that the operating system or filesystem is slow with creating a reliable and specific filesystem state at the same time. This applies to Linux in general and to ZFS as filesystem regardless of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an explicit `cd` first:

```
( cd /f1/f2/my_folder && tar -c -f - .  ) | tar -x -f - -C /f1/f2/f4
```

... but since you are already familiar with the `-C` option, you could uses that on the archive-generating side of the pipe as well:

```
tar -c -f - -C /f1/f2/my_folder . | tar -x -f - -C /f1/f2/f4
```

If you want to copy the `my_folder` directory and not just its contents,

```
tar -c -f - -C /f1/f2 my_folder | tar -x -f - -C /f1/f2/f4
```

Personally, I think this is a bit messy, what with all the options, so I would probably use `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -a /f1/f2/my_folder/ /f1/f2/f4
```

or, to copy the directory (not just contents),

```
rsync -a /f1/f2/my_folder /f1/f2/f4
```

(Note the subtle difference in the source path.)

Comment: Not all `tar` implementations support `-C` in extract mode.

Comment: @schily I'm assuming that the user's `tar` does as they successfully use `-C` with `-x` already.